# Is a reboot required for SSL V3 disable on Windows? - Poodle exploit

Tags: windows, security, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, poodle

We are trying to disable SSL V3 on numerous windows servers; as a part of it , registries are being updated remotely via script.
Problem is lots of reboots are required post registry change. Is there a way around it , can service be restarted on the server to not accept SSL V3 anymore post registry change?

Edit: Little more clarification, this is about "SSL V3 server" disable; on windows 2012 R2 Servers.

Comment: SSL V3 is used on servers and clients alike - can you provide enough detail of exactly which SSL V3 you are disabling and how, to get better advice?

Comment: Lots of reboots? AFAIK one reboot is enough after the registry change.

Comment: @Daniel lots of servers equals to lots of reboots, one per each; sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes... probably... if you're talking about applications that call into schannel.dll.

You mentioned "Servers" and you mentioned "SSlv3" which is a protocol. Changes to this registry key requires a reboot.

Read this Microsoft article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245030

That's basically the bible of this topic.

Notice that the article says "Changes to the CIPHERS key or the HASHES key take effect immediately, without a system restart."

However, you are changing the PROTOCOLS key. So, restart.

**EDIT:** Oh, I forgot to mention the most important part -- changes to this registry key, they only affect applications that call into the Schannel DLL. (Such as IIS, RDP, SQL Server, etc.) They have NO EFFECT on applications that use a third party library such as OpenSSL. In those apps, it is impossible for us to know whether it will require a reboot or not because it depends on the app.

Answer (score 2):

You can restart the HTTP service using `net stop http` and `net start http`. It will obvious only affect applications using it (like IIS).

You will also need to restart any services depending on HTTP service and close any other process using `\Device\Http\*` (otherwise the service won't stop).

Here's a PowerShell script to do all this.
(It uses [handle.exe](https://live.sysinternals.com/handle.exe) from https://live.sysinternals.com/ and doesn't consider multiple levels of dependent services.)

```
$depencies = Get-Service HTTP -DependentServices |? Status -eq Running
Stop-Service $depencies
.\handle.exe -nobanner -a \Device\Http\ |? { $_ -match '\s+pid:\s*(?<pid>\d+)\s+' } |% { $matches.pid } | gu |% { Stop-Process -Id $_ -Confirm }
Restart-Service HTTP
Start-Service $depencies
```

(I tested this only on Windows 7.)